# Install programs from terminal

Tags: software-installation

i am a newbie to linux!i am having a trouble to install adobe flash player plugin! can any one please tell me how to install it clearly? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Software Center?

Comment: Chrome uses its own flash player, independent from the one installed on your system, so installing adobe-flashplugin-installer won't help you. You may want to ask a new question about why your Chrome's flash player crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

This will install flash

EDIT: For chrome:

```
 sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Comment: i have installed it! and after opening the chrome and when i play any video it says "shockwave flash has crashed"

Comment: The earlier command was for Firefox, I've edited the post